# How to  make a Web browser (e.g. Firefox Web Browser) embedded an Gnome Desktop in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04

How to make a Web browser (e.g. Firefox Web Browser) embedded  an Gnome  Desktop Workspace Background

and when system starts embedded web browser should be on the desktop

Comment: Like active desktop in windows XP!, Absolutely no idea, i've never thought about it, I will find a good answer, just give me some time, thanks for the great question (that makes us impossible :-))

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches.  I'll give you both, the first should work for your specific answer and the second you may find more general and applicable overall.

First, shut all applications except the web browser and make sure the browser is in the workspace your have chosen for it.

Now select the System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications... menu choice.
Then click the Options tab
Click the "Remember Currently Running Application"

Now you could close the dialog and when you log in you should get the browser started in that workspace.  The "Remember..." button has a typo, it should say "Applications" (plural) because all running applications are remembered.

Option two is to select the "Automatically remember running applications when logging out" check box.  This way everything you are running when logging out gets restored and for many of us that makes for better connectivity between login sessions.  This may become more to your liking.